# Python os output

Tags: python, linux, operating-system, os.system

My code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

## print linux os command output

import os

p = os.popen ('fortune | cowsay',"r")
while 1:
    line = p.readline()
    if not line: break
    print line

retvalue = os.system ("fortune | cowsay")
print retvalue
```

Output is:

```
 ______________________________________

< Stay away from flying saucers today. >

 --------------------------------------

        \   ^__^

         \  (oo)\_______

            (__)\       )\/\

                ||----w |

                ||     ||

 ______________________________________
/ Q: What happens when four WASPs find \
| themselves in the same room? A: A    |
\ dinner party.                        /
 --------------------------------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
0
```

My questions are:

1. Why there is an empty line after each line in the output of the first `cowsay` with `os.popen`?
2. Why there is a zero added at the end of the output of the second cowsay `os.system`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the lines returned by `p.readline` already have newlines appended to the end of them. The `print` function adds an additional newline, for a total of two. That's why there's a blank line between each one. try doing `print line.rstrip("\n")`.

`os.system` returns a number indicating the exit status of the executed command. `fortune | cowsay` exited without any problems, so its exit code was zero. The cow and speech balloon isn't being printed by your `print` function; they're being sent to stdout by the `system` call itself. If you don't want the zero, just don't print `retvalue`.

Comment: thanks @kevin your answer worked perfectly well. new to python and still learning. thanks for help! this is fun!!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of printing line as is, try doing

```
print line.rstrip('\n')
```

The 0 at the end is due to your `print retvalue` at the end.